# Android Fragments fundamentals: why? Is this conceptually wrong?

Tags: android, interface, fragment, communication

I have a question about "proper programming" in Android.

I am currently developing an app using fragments. It involves dynamically added fragments to Activity, fragments inflated from XML, nested fragments from XML or dynamically added. Let's just say, a bit of everything.

The concept this question focuses on is the communication process involved with fragments. So, I've read the docs and this is not the first time I try to use fragments.

The common sense (and docs) tell that if a Fragment wants to speak or communicate with it's activity, we should use an interface.

Example:

**TestFragment**

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

  private TestFragmentInterface listener; 

  public interface TestFragmentInterface {

      void actionMethod();

  }


  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      if (getActivity() instanceof TestFragmentInterface) {
          listener = (TestFragmentInterface) getActivity();
      }

      // sending the event
      if (listener != null) listener.actionMethod();
  }

}
```

**TestActivity**

```
public class Test implements TestFragmentInterface {

  @Override
  public void actionMethod() {
    ..
  }
}
```

Everything fine here.

This improves re-usability, as my TestFragment this way can interact with any kind of Activity, given the Activity implements the interface I declare.

The other way around, the Activity can interact with the fragment by holding a reference and calling its public methods. This is also the suggested way to fragment-to-fragment communication, using the Activity as a bridge.

This is cool, but sometimes it feels like using an interface for this is just a bit "too much".

**Question A**

In the scenario the fragments I attach have a pretty focused role, meaning they are done for that particular activity and would not be used otherwise, is it conceptually wrong to ignore the interface implementation and just do something like

```
((TestActivity) getActivity().myCustomMethod();
```

?

This also goes to the scenario where (not my case, but just taking it as a "at its worst") my activity has to deal with a wide variety of these DIFFERENT fragments, meaning it should implement one method for every fragment it should handle. This brings the code to a big mess of "potentially not-needed lines".

Moving further on: still with the use of "focused" fragments, aimed to work only under certain way, what is with the use of nested fragments?

Added them like

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {


  private void myTestMethod() {

    NestedFragment nested = new NestedFragment();

    getChildFragmentManager()
      .beginTransaction()
      .add(R.id.container, nested)
      .commit();
  }

}
```

this binds NestedFragment to TestFragment. I say it again, NestedFragment, just like TestFragment, is to be used only in this way, it has no meaning to work otherwise.

Back to the question, how should I behave in this situation?

**Question B**

1) should I provide an interface in NestedFragment, and make so that TestFragments implements NestedFragmentInterface? In this case I would act as following

**NestedFragment**

```
public class NestedFragment extends Fragment {

  private NestedFragmentInterface listener; 

  public interface NestedFragmentInterface {

      void actionMethodNested();

  }


  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      if (getParentFragment() instanceof NestedFragmentInterface) {
          listener = (NestedFragmentInterface) getParentFragment();
      }

      // sending the event
      if (listener != null) listener.actionMethodNested();
  }

}
```

2) should (or could) I ignore interface, and just call

```
getParentFragment().publicParentMethod();
```

?

3) should I create the interface in NestedFragment, but let the **activity** implements it, so that the **activity** will call TestFragment ?

**Question C**

Regarding the idea of using the Activity as a bridge between fragments, I believe it is made so for proper handling lifecycle of all these objects. Is it still viable to do a direct fragment-to-fragment (using interface or directly call public methods) while trying to handle manually the exception the system might throw me?

Comment: See if this helps: https://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html

Comment: I've read the link you posted, and while it was indeed an interesting article with lot of information, I'm afraid it just doesn't answer my questions. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try to clear it all a little bit.

First of all, consider you approach of setting listener for fragment. It is no good to set listener in onViewCreated method, because it leeds to excess reseting listener any fragment is created. It is enough to set it up into onAttach method.

I told about code lines. Take me to notice, it is good to have BaseFragment implemented common behavior in you app as setting FragmentListener creating view from resource.

And more than that to reduce code lines and to get part of code reuse you can use generic in BaseFragment. So look at next code snippet:

```
public abstract BaseFragment<T extends BaseFragmentListener> extends Fragment {

  T mListener;

  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (Activity instanceof T)
      mListener = (T) activity; 
  }

  abstract int getLayoutResourceId();

  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(getLayoutResourceId(), null);
        // you can use some view injected tools here, mb ButterKnife 
        return layout;
    }
}
```

Answer A (For Question A):

If you have fragment only exactly one activity you need to decide: "Do you really need to use Fragment here?". But mb it is good to have fragment exactly for one activity to extract some view logic from activity and clearing base logic. But for clearing base architecture logic for your app use Listeners. This will make life easier for other developers

Answer B:
For nested fragments you need to solve, what they need to use exact activity or just fragments and use it as a bridge to other system. If you know that nested fragment will be nested all time you, you need to declare parent fragment as listener otherwise you have to use other approach.

Notice:
As the base approach to communicate between diff part of App you can use events, try too look at event bus for example. It gives you common approach for communication and you can extract logic of calling custom methods of listeners and more another, all logic will be situated into handling events and you will have one mediator system for cooperation.

Answer C:
I partially explain one of approaches to cooperating between fragments. Using one event dispatcher avoids you to have many listeners for all different communication. Some times it is very profitably.

Or I think it is more usable to use Activity, or other class lives in Activity, for a mediator for Fragments cooperation because there is many situation of Fragments changing during lifecycle both handling and system. And it focuses all this logic in one place and makes your code more clear.

Hope my considerations helps you.

Comment: Thank you, this was a great answer, detailed in the logic and helpful, gave me some good ideas : )

Answer (score 10):

Ill do my best to answer the wall of text here :)

Question A:

Fragments are designed to be reusable modules that can be plug and played with any activity. Because of this the only correct way way to interface with the activity is to have the activity inherit from a interface that the fragment understands.

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

  private MapFragmentInterface listener; 

  public interface MapFragmentInterface {

      //All methods to interface with an activity

  }


  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // sending the event
      if (listener != null) listener.anyMethodInTheAboveInterface();
  }

}
```

Then have the activity implement the interface

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implement MapFragmentInterface{

//All methods need to be implemented here
}
```

This allows your fragment to be used with any activity as long as the activity implements this interface. The reason why you need this interface is because the fragment can be used with any activity. Calling a method like

```
((TestActivity) getActivity().myCustomMethod();
```

relies on the fact that your fragment only can work within a test activity and therefore "breaks" the rules of fragments.

Question B and C:

Assuming that you are following the correct guidelines for fragments and that they are independent modules. Then you should never have a situation where fragments need to know about each other. 99% of the time that people think they need fragments to directly communicate they can re-factor their problem to the situation I gave above by using a MVC patten or something similar. Have the activity act like the controller and tell the fragments when they need to update and then create a separate data store.

Comment: Then, from what you write, I get that what I'm doing is possible but not suggested as the usage is outside of the original scope. It is not something that is harmful, but simply not used as originally intended. How much am I wrong? : )

Comment: Your 100% correct. Like with all programming there are many ways to do things. A lot of the time I will even do it exactly how you described because I know my fragment will only be used in this one activity. However if you are trying to be "correct" you should do it through an interface to make your code ad decoupled as possible. If you have time and money you should always build your app the correct way though :)